# codemirror live syntax highlighting: extend for {tags}

Tags: javascript, syntax, highlight

I have implemented Codemirror http://marijn.haverbeke.nl/codemirror/ to work as a live text editor within an application and it works perfect.

The only thing I would love to do is create a custom color (e.g. red) for tags used in our system.

We would be using tags like {something here} or {{something here}}

doe anyone know how I can extend codemirror to flag those tags in red?

Comment: ok, this is old, but someone might find this useful, there is an add-on (i am the author)  [which makes a custom codemirror parser from a grammar in json format](http://stackoverflow.com/a/26395829/3591273)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I think you have to implement your own parser resp. extend an existing one.

Manual on how to implement a parser: http://marijn.haverbeke.nl/codemirror/manual.html#writeparser

Comment: thanks, I'm trying to find a somewhat easier option to begin with. Since I'm only looking for one or two tag pairs, it might be possible to add these to an existing parser...?

Comment: I never wrote a custom parser. But extending an existing one should not be a big deal. The 'parsedummy.js' might be a good starting point since this parser only handles line indentation.

Comment: Looks like they have the example they have does this for you already: http://codemirror.net/demo/mustache.html