# How to write a parser in javascript to parse text in editor into JSON with a model?

Tags: javascript, json, parser-generator

I don't know if it is the place to ask this. But I will try.

What I need is, for example, if user writes some text in Code Mirror editor like:

```
a1=Some Text
    a11 = Some Child text
```

and the parser should check if the grammer is correct, and parse it to:

```
 {
    'a1' : {
             'value' : "Some Text",
             'a11' : "some child text"
    }
 }
```

Something like this according to the gramme.

So, is there any parser library or something in javascript?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You should be able to use [PEG.js](http://pegjs.majda.cz/) to parse the text on the client side. I would also recommend to start off from writing a proper grammar for whatever valid input you are expecting from the user.

Comment: Yes, I heard about PEG. Also there is Jison I guess.

Comment: I have used PEG and it has been working out great for me. They have a console where you can type the grammar and the input and see the parser in action. Click on the 'Online Version' from their main page.

Answer (score 0):

This is a bit older, but will give an answer based on a [codemirror grammar add-on](https://github.com/foo123/codemirror-grammar) i have written (as a result of some projects which required syntax-highlight for various custom languages).

One defines a grammar in JSON format for any language (or variation since json grammars can extend other json grammars) and the add-on creates automaticaly a codemirror parser which can include syntax parts and syntax-errors, autocompletion and more

See [live example here](http://foo123.github.io/examples/codemirror-grammar/)